# R.java error while building

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, compiler-errors

I opened my project as usual in Android Studio 1.3.1, add modification and start a build, and a error occurred:

> Error:(1630, 32) error:  expected
>   Error:(1630, 38)
>   error: illegal start of type
>   Error:(1630, 39) error: 
>   expected

Showing me:

```
public static final class drawable {
        public static final int 31205=0x7f020000;
        public static final int abc_ab_share_pack_mtrl_alpha=0x7f020001;
        public static final int abc_btn_check_material=0x7f020002;
        public static final int abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_000=0x7f020003;
        public static final int abc_btn_check_to_on_mtrl_015=0x7f020004;
        [...]
```

I reverted my changes, but the errors still happen.

I have no idea what is wrong, since I used the reverted code before without any problem.

Comment: Clean the project (Build->Clean)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java variable names can't start with number like here:

```
public static final int 31205=0x7f020000;
```

Maybe you use a drawable resource which's name starts with a number.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I downloaded by mistake a picture with that name in the res folder.